# Program to read words without vowels from a text file into a list

Tags: python

Trying to make a program that reads a text file and stores words without vowels into a list which it prints at the end. I'm using n to ensure the word doesn't get added in several times. What am I doing wrong?

```
#Function to print words from text file with no vowels
def noVowels():
    n = 0
    l = []
    f = open("text.txt",'r')
    r = f.read()
    s = r.split()
    for i in s:
        n = 0
        for j in i:
            if j.lower() in 'aeiou' and n == 0:
                n = 1
            elif n == 0:
                print(n)
                l.append(i)
                n = 1
    print(l)

noVowels()
```

Comment: Ask yourself - you have only one value in `n`, how can it remember counts for **all** words?

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def noVowels():
    l = []
    with open("text.txt", 'r') as f:
        r = f.read()
    s = r.split()
    for i in s:
        contains_vowel = False  # Initialize the flag for each word
        for j in i:
            if j.lower() in 'aeiou':  # If a vowel is found, set the flag to True
                contains_vowel = True
                break  # Exit the inner loop as we found a vowel
        if not contains_vowel:  # If no vowel was found in the entire word, append it to the list
            l.append(i)
    print(l)

noVowels()
```

I've also used a `with` statement to handle the file. This ensures that the file will be closed properly even if an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a set.

Something like this:

```
VOWELS = set('AEIOUaeiou')

def noVowels(filename='text.txt'):
    control = set()
    result = list()
    with open(filename) as data:
        for line in data:
            for word in line.split():
                if not any(c in VOWELS for c in word):
                    if not word in control:
                        control.add(word)
                        result.append(word)
    return result
```

You could just use the set to return the result but that may not maintain the order in which the words/tokens were observed. If order isn't important, just use the set.

You could avoid using a set by searching the list (keyword *in*) but that could be slow if your dataset is large